# Back button for android is not working for apk file

Tags: android, actionscript-3, apk

I am using Flash CS6 to create an android app. I am trying to code for my back button. It works well when i run the file in flash but after I published it out into my handphone, the back button brings me from page 3 to page 1 instead of from page 3 to page 2. I am doing my coding in the frame itself and not by class.

The code I have used is below:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;

stop();
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownHandler159)

function onKeyDownHandler159(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if( event.keyCode == Keyboard.BACK)
    {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopImmediatePropagation();
         NativeApplication.nativeApplication.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownHandler159);
         gotoAndStop (14);
         NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownHandler159)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using keyboardEvent.KEY_UP rather than KEY_DOWN. Key down can be interpreted in different ways, especially on a mobile device. I've never had any issues with Key up